# Anchor tag in responsive website

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive

I created a "one-page scroll" responsive site. In the navigation items I added the following code to make the page jump to that specific section:

```
// For example the contact menu

   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

// Then in the contact section I added this
   <a name="contact"></a>
```

This works perfectly in the full width website.
However, since my site is responsive, in the mobile view, when I click on "benefits" for example, it does jump to the benefits section, but it adds the height of the menu. Is there a way to not get all that height?

You can view the page [here](http://vpay.cl/test/index.html).

[image: Here you can see what I mean]

Comment: now top position is hidden by menu, so add dynamic top when device is mobile.

Comment: Can you explain how to achieve that please? Thanks

Comment: you can create animated scroll using jquery, its very flexible

Comment: I was hoping to achieve this by using CSS only since I have no knowledge of jQuery

Comment: ah ok. you have use dynamic top margin using js. I can give you a hint. when you click on the menu icon add top margin to page content.